# Biography of rasool(pbuh)

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, books, seerah

Can anyone suggest the best book for understanding muhammed rasool (pbuh)?
Please give any link for pdf or suggest any online shop for purchasing.The book or pdf must be either in english or in malayalam.

Comment: From where i can get this?

Comment: jazakallah khair

Comment: Book recommendations are a bad fit for our main site and in stackexchange in general as they are generally subjective. Maybe [this Meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/list-of-islam-related-books-in-english) is of use for you!

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few biographies of the Prophet, suggesting the best one among them would likely be opinion based and would vary with the aim of the study. Ar-Raheeq Al-Makhtum (The Sealed Nectar) is one possible example available [here](https://archive.org/details/TheSealedNectar_201501).